# WordPress update 4.7 - the 70.000+ news posts became "Uncategorized"

Tags: categories

Dear WordPress experts,

I updated a news website to Wordpress 4.7 from 4.6.1 or 4.6. The update ran well, the routine message showed up saying that the database as well should be updated. I clicked "OK". In a short while a 504 Gateway Timeout error occured. Afterwards, in the WordPress dashboard none of the 70.000+ posts has a category, all of the posts are marked as "Uncategorized". Once I try to edit and choose one of the 300+ categories and publish - nothing changes, the post remains "Uncategorized".

In PHPMyAdmin all the tables are fine, wp_terms is fine, all the categories with their IDs are listed there. However, the front-end and the WP-dashboard show no category to be assigned to a post.

PLease advise.

Comment: What about reverting to a backup before the update and run it again? Maybe increase `max_execution_time` and memory limits before doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The max_execution_time (the time limit for server requests) was too short and seized the database update after 4.7 was installed.

I have just downgraded the WordPress version back to the previous version 6.1:
- WP-includes and WP-admin folders were overwritten along with the root files of the WordPress install (robots.txt and wp-config.php  are not affected at all as they are not included in the fresh WordPress release files).

After the downgrade all the categories are fine, just the news articles that were published in the meantime had "Uncategorized" category that I easily removed and assigned them correctly in the dashboard.

The solution is easy - thanks for the help!